# Why does my Toyota Corolla 1500cc with 16 valves lose a half litre of water in the radiator after 100 km run?

Tags: toyota, coolant, radiator, corolla, water-leak

I have recently changed an engine and it's quite new made in Japan. I have also changed the water tank of the radiator. Hence no leak and nothing at all but after running it for 100km it reduces about half litre of water in the radiator.

Why?

Comment: How are you sure its not leaking? Also does the car run hot / overheat a bit during the 100km ?

Comment: If you operate for another 100 km, does it also lose a half liter of coolant? If not, the initial filling was excessive and being forced out of the system.

Comment: I agree with both comments here.  If it overheats or if it continues to lose coolant, then it's possibly either a leak that you're not seeing or a bad head gasket.  It's also possible that you didn't fully bleed the cooling system and the 'lost' coolant is actually still in there; it's just taken the place of air bubbles that were previously there. Further testing on your part is required for someone to give a better response.